# How could I make the modal show up after clicking the Update(submit) button?

Tags: python, jquery, django

This is the footer code:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button id="employee_update_btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-round ">Update</button>
                                          </div>
                                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
                                                        {% if success %}
                                                        <script>
                                                        $('#employee.employee_id_{{ employee.employee_id }}').show();
                                                        </script>
                                                        {% endif %}
                                                    </script>


                                    </form>
```

I wanted to open the modal after clicking the Update button.

views.py

```
 return render(request, 'index.html', context={'success': True})
```

the Modal i wanted to open:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="employee.employee_id_{{ employee.employee_id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none; overflow: auto;"  aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
                              <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                  <div class="card">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                      <div class="modal-header">
                                            <div class="card-header-success" >
                                              <h4 align="center" class="card-title">EMPLOYEE PROFILE</h4>
                                            </div>

                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `{% if success %}...` will break your code inserting a `<script>` tag inside another.

Anyway, to accomplish what you want, the following should do the trick.

```js
$("#employee_update_btn").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();  // Prevent default submit action
    // show the modal
    $("#employee_employee_id_{{ employee.employee_id }}").show();
});`
```

Note that I've changed your modal ID getting rid of the dot in it since it will break the selector, update your html as follows

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="employee_employee_id_{{ employee.employee_id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none; overflow: auto;"  aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
[...]
```

If you are using bootstrap as a css framework, keep in mind that you should init the modal before interacting with it.